# Setting the default terminal editor on a Mac running Yosemite or El Capitan

Tags: bash, macos, editor

I have read any number of posts explaining how to set the default editor for the terminal on a mac o stackoverflow.  They all describe the same thing inserting a line in .bash_profile (or sometimes .bashrc) like:

```
export EDITOR='/Applications/TextWrangler.app'
```

or:

```
export EDITOR='/Applications/TextWrangler.app/Contents/MacOS/TextWrangler'
```

Nothing works.  The terminal continues to default to `TextEdit`.

Has apple set this profile somewhere else in a way that overrides `.bash_profile`?

Can someone help me with this?

Comment: this may help http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/73823/how-does-mountain-lion-set-the-default-text-editor-for-the-open-t-terminal-co

Comment: The terminal by itself does not launch any editor at all. You need to describe the scenario which doesn't work in more detail. What do you do which causes TextEdit to launch?

Comment: open -e somefile.txt

Comment: above is in error.  What should open default editor but opens TextEdit instated is open -t

Comment: Looking at your link (which is from 2012 and way before the current OS X versions, it suggests changing the LShanders setting in the LaunchServices plist, which determines which file the Finder uses to open files of certain types. This does not affect the default browser for terminal. From all references I have found the bash default editor should be determined by the .bash_profile file.

Answer (score 1):

According to the man page for `open`:

> -e     Causes the file to be opened with /Applications/TextEdit"

In any case, `open` is an OS X command which will use the associations that are set for the file, the same as Finder does. The only things that will obey `EDITOR` are command line programs designed to run in a Unix environment.